# How to display international products in ecommerce?

Tags: e-commerce, internationalisation

For an ecommerce site that sells the same product but different packaging for US and Canada, how should I display the product?

1. The product is not sold to Canada, only US. Therefore you cannot buy the Canadian version.
2. It is required to show Canadian version due to regulations (package is different and product description has French version)
3. There is no value for the user to see canadian version of product as a separate product.

Should I simply apply the Canadian images and French description within the product detail page? So the user can still see that content.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are in an ecommerce application there should be some type of localization, ie. a .ca domain for the Canadian store, or a currency switcher.

Once on the correct locale then show the products for that locale, default your locale for the highest amount of users.

If you can't have any localization and as you mentioned you don't want to show it as a separate product then I would seek out the help of a lawyer for what is the minimal requirements for displaying the french product (annoying I know I've worked in en/fr e-commerce for 3 years) and then add that to the base listing, with a note that product packaging may vary based on region.